# How to call a function in a user defined function im Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use *defun* to define a function in my .emacs file:

```
(defun myfun ()
   "i am already loaded the color-theme lib"
   (color-theme-initialize)
   (color-theme-darkblue))
```

Then I want to use this function in my mode-hook:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
   '(lambda ()
       (myfun)
       (...)))
```

But I got an error saying that the **color-theme-initialize** function is void.

P.S. my ~/.emacs snippet

```
(progn (require 'color-theme)
       (color-theme-initialize))

(progn (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
       (setq-default tab-width 2)
       (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (color-theme-resolve)
             (show-paren-mode t)
             (linum-mode t)))
```

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using?  I think that color-theme-initialize is a new feature of Emacs 24?

Comment: My Emacs is 23.3.1. I get the color-theme lib from http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/, and it is the lib defined that function. This lib works fine interactively.

Comment: @davidshen84: If the version used is really the one hosted here http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/ I don't see how you can call `color-theme-initialize` interactively because this function *doesn't* exist. So maybe another version of `color-theme` has been bundled with your emacs or you've installed on with your package manager (`emacs-goodies` or something similar). See my post below to know how to locate this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `require` (or otherwise load) the library which provides `color-theme-initialize`. I'm guessing `(require 'color-theme)`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error, it's not your function that cannot be called, but the
function named `color-theme-initialize`. This function has been
removed some times ago but can still be present in some older version
of `color-theme`. Thus, check your version of `color-theme` and see if
there is a function called `color-theme-initialize` (with
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`color-theme-initialize`<kbd>RET</kbd>). If
the function is present then you have to `(require 'color-theme)`,
otherwise you don't need to call this function.

Comment: No. I am using this function right now, interactively in Emacs.